# Where are CSV files saved?

Tags: powershell, csv

So in PowerShell I've finally figured out how to read two variables, do a WMI query, and write three variables to a CSV file. I want the exported csv file to be created in the present working directory, but I'm finding it in C:\Windows\system32. I believe these are the relevant lines from my code; let me know if you need more:

```
$resultfile = ".\Check-Results.csv"
$csv = "<$server>,<$service>,<$status>`r`n"
<ping check, foreach loop, wmi query here, etc...>
$csv +=$server + "," + $service + "," + $status + "`r`n"
$fso = New-Object -ComObject scripting.filesystemobject
$file = $fso.CreateTextFile($resultfile,$true)
$file.write($csv)
$file.close()
```

My understanding would be that the dot-slash would be all that's needed to get the results file in the PWD, but I guess not. Incidentally, my script has to be PS 2.0 compatible, so I can't just do Export-CSV -append.

For alroc: What my script is doing is getting a server name and a PortWWN from a csv file using Import-CSV. Then I loop through the list of servers in a foreach loop to query WMI for the Emulex Port that matches the PortWWN, then extracts the Port State (Link Down, Operational, etc.)

So I begin with two variables from the Import-CSV, $server and $wwn, and end up with three variables, $server, $wwn, and $status. The three variables need to be written to a new CSV file. I know that PS 2.0 has Export-CSV, but it does not have the -append parameter--that's a 3.0 feature. So my early results were displaying only the last result in the loop.

I got the idea for fsobjects from [The Scripting Guy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/07/09/hey-scripting-guy-how-do-i-create-a-csv-file-from-within-windows-powershell.aspx) and was pleased to see the results work perfectly, except the file isn't where I expected it to be. This script has to be run by relatively inexperienced PS users, so it has to be fairly idiot-proof. They're going to copy the script and source CSV file to a computer with PS 2.0, run the script, then look at the result file, and I want everything to be in one place.

Comment: I know little of PowerShell, but I expect that that is the PWD and you need to change it: [Managing Current Location](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315262.aspx). Or explicitly give the path instead of using `.\`.

Comment: Forget using COM object to handle files in PowerShell. You've got get-content, set-content and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that the dot-slash would make it save in the current working directory. Each process has a current working directory and powershell is no different so to see it's "real" current working directory you could do something like the following:

```
Write-Host ([System.Environment]::CurrentDirectory)
```

However Powershell is special in that the location you see at prompt is the current providers location. That is why if you type something like:

```
cd cert:
```

You would be at a prompt with the following:

```
PS Cert:\>
```

This "cert:\" drive is not a "real" location and so couldn't possibly be set as the processes current working directory. This is why powershell has it's own (location) as well as it's processes current working directory, though you only see the former.

Cmdlets are usually designed to use powershell's location but if you directly use .NET classes or call third party programs then the current working directory will be that of the powershell process. If you want to know where your CSV's are being saved then add the following to your script:

```
Write-Host ([System.Environment]::CurrentDirectory)
```

Or if your current powershell location is an actual filesystem location then you could set the processes current working directory to the powershell's location with the following:

```
[System.Environment]::CurrentDirectory = Get-Location
```

Comment: Thank you, DanL. That was it. My ISE's pwd was set to windows\system32, and my console's pwd was set to a network share. I had no idea.

Comment: At the top of my script, I added your suggestion of [System.Environment]::CurrentDirectory = Get-Location and at the end displayed the directory for the user to find the results file. Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

If you call PowerShell from a batch file, it will often start in `C:\Windows\System32\` because that's where `cmd.exe` is.

To set the location to where the script file being run is, you can use this:

```
Set-Location $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
```

If that doesn't work in PowerShell 2.0, try:

```
Set-Location $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
```

Check [`Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) for more information.  That's PowerShell 4.0, but its very similar to 2.0, and I can't find the old 2.0 reference.

Answer (score 1):

CSV files are saved wherever you tell the script to save them. In this case, it'll be a file in the current working directory where you ran the script from.

But, you're writing your CSV as though it were VBScript. You ought to be writing The PowerShell Way(tm). It'll be faster, cleaner, and much easier to read. Unfortunately, I can't give you specific recommendations as you've not shown the details of what your script is doing, but you're probably going to want to create a custom `PSObject` contain the results of the cmdlets that you execute to get your ping & WMI data (which will **not** be the methods that you're currently using), then output with `export-csv` (which is in PowerShell 2.0, so you're covered there).

If you stick with what you're doing right now, your output should be via the following (and not the FSO):

```
Set-Content -path $resultfile -force -value $csv
```

Comment: alroc, fair enough. I thought the file would be saved in the pwd when I specified the dot-slash, but that's not happening. I'll add more to my question.

Comment: When in doubt, specify the full absolute path. Or start with a known environment variable.